# How to download packages without compiling/installing them?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there any command-line switch to `stack` that tells it to download all relevant packages without compiling/installing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you probably want a combination of the `--prefetch` and `--dry-run` flags.  For example, the following command:

```
stack build --prefetch --dry-run acme-missiles
```

downloads the `acme-missiles-0.3.tar.gz` source file without building it.  If you later run `stack build acme-missiles`, it should configure and build it from the previously downloaded source.

Comment: Does this also fetch all dependencies of `acme-missiles`?

Comment: Yup.  It should go through the process of downloading everything needed to build the indicated package but without actually compiling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download sources of the package locally you can use `stack unpack` command:

```
stack unpack typerep-map-0.3.0
```

The same can be done with `cabal-install` as well but with `cabal get` command:

```
cabal get typerep-map-0.3.0
```

Comment: would you happen to know the difference between `stack build --prefetch` and `stack unpack`?

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to be unpacking the packages' source to the current directory. Not what I wanted.